# Scrapy, problem input multiple spider's variable in CrawlerRunner

Tags: python, variables, scrapy, runner

I  write my scrapy spider that start with two class variable, and then want to run it from Runner. 
I did try:

```
yield runner.crawl(MySpider1, variable1, variable2)
```

or

```
yield runner.crawl(MySpider1, [variable1, variable2])
```

or

```
yield runner.crawl(MySpider1, (variable1, variable2))
```

or

```
yield runner.crawl(MySpider1(variable1, variable2))
```

but got

> missing 1 required postional argument

here is my code:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    def _init__(self, variable1, variable2, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*arg, **kwargs)
        self.variable1 = variable1
        self.variable2 = variable2

    # below should be any normal spider's parser





class Run_Spider_From_SubClass(SpiderEmail):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        configure_logging()
        self.runner = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def crawl(self):
        for variable1, variable2 in mydict.item():
            yield self.runner.crawl(MySpider, variable1, varialbe2)  # input issue that result in missing 1 positional argument
        reactor.stop()

    def run_spider_in_loop(self):
        self.crawl()
        reactor.run()

runner = Run_Spider_From_SubClass()
runner.run_spider_in_loop()
```

what should be correct way to input spider's variable in Runnner? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to override `__init__` in `MySpider` (and notice that you have a missing `_` there anyway).

To pass parameters, you need to use *named/keyword* arguments, not *positional* arguments:

```
yield self.runner.crawl(MySpider, variable1=variable1, variable2=variable2)
```

This will automatically make it available in your spider as a class variable: `self.variable1`.

Comment: Thank, this is working now. I mess with super() from Run_Spider_From_SubClass.